# .Net Namespace Question

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I have two namespaces:

1) Foo.Bar

2) Another.Foo.Bar

From a class in namespace 2, how do I reference a class in namespace 1?  Using Foo.Bar leaves you in namespace 2 still...

I hope this is reasonably clear!

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [global qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Just add:

```
using GFooBar = global::Foo.Bar;
```

Then refer to it as:

```
GFooBar.MyClass = new GFooBar.MyClass();
```

or

```
global::Foo.Bar.MyClass = new global::Foo.Bar.MyClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the corner case that `global::Foo.Bar` was introduced for. `global::` means the outer-scope.

Comment: Hank:  It needs to be global::Foo.Bar.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Fully qualify the class name.  The fully qualified name of types in your first namespace is not the same as fully qualified names of types in the second.

So, from code in the `Another.Foo.Bar` namespace you can say `Foo.Bar.SomeType`, and it's distinguished (in C#, at least — VB works a little different) from the `Foo.Bar.SomeType` in your current namespace, because that type's full name is `Another.Foo.Bar.SomeType`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (C#) :/  They are in different assemblies though - perhaps that is something to do with it.